# Let $f(x)$ be polynomial of degree four

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)$ polynomial of degree four where: $$f(1)=1,f(2)=4,f(3)=9,f(4)=16, f(7)=409$$

Find $$f(5)=??$$

Comment: By "fourth order function", do you mean a polynomial of degree four?

Comment: It would be nice if you told us what your ideas are so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: "Let $f(x)$ be polynomial of degree four" is neither a question nor any kind of indication of what your question might be about.

Answer (score 4):

A nice trick is to write the polynomial in Newton form. As an example, to find the quadratic polynomial which interpolates $(0,1),(1,3),(3,19)$, you use the form

$$y=a+b(x-0)+c(x-0)(x-1).$$

The idea is that you start with a constant, then you add a linear polynomial that vanishes at the first node, then you add a quadratic that vanishes at the first two nodes, etc. The nice thing about this is that you don't have to solve a system of linear equations, instead you can find all of the coefficients with substitution. (Technically you *are* solving a system of linear equations, but the system is triangular, which makes it much easier to solve.)

So here, plug in $x=0,y=1$ to get $a=1$. Now plug in $x=1,y=3$ to get $1+b=3$ so $b=2$. Now plug in $x=3,y=19$ to get $1+6+6c=19$ so $c=2$.

For your particular case, you can pull a particularly clever trick. The first four terms all agree with $y=x^2$, so you can find the interpolating polynomial through $(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(7,360)$ and then add it to $x^2$ to get your answer. ($360$ came from $409-7^2$.)

Comment: man, it's hard problem, and I'm beginner, so you mean that $f(5)=49$?

Comment: You don't need to "solve" anything. That is just interpolation and the coefficients of the Newton Polynomial is given by the divided differences, which has a simple recursion formulae. See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial), in particular the application section.

Comment: @mame No. Following the trick I suggested, you want to find $a$ such that $a(7-1)(7-2)(7-3)(7-4)=360$. Then your polynomial is $x^2+a(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$.

Comment: @user251257 Divided differences are just another way of writing down back-substitution for this kind of triangular system of linear equations.

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to invent the wheel again and again :)

Comment: man I followed your trick and I get $f(5)=49$?????????

Comment: @mame That looks right, actually; sorry I didn't check the numbers myself.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean $f(x)$ is a fourth degree polynomial, $f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$.  From your data you can write five equations-the one from $f(2)=4$ is $16a+8b+4c+2d+e=4$  Write the other four and solve.

Comment: sorry, $f(7)=409$

Answer (score 1):

Since the first four terms in sequence $x=1,2,3,4$ follow $x^2$, we can assume that a term $a\binom {x-1}4$ has no influence over those terms, so we have

$$f(x)=x^2+a\binom{x-1}4$$

At $x=7$ this becomes $49+a\binom 64=15a+49$ which when compared with $f(7)=409$ gives us $a=24$.  This gives us $f(5)=24\binom 44+25$...

Comment: you mean that $f(5)=60$?

Comment: No, see my update...  The final function is equivalent to $f(x)=60\binom{x-1}4+x^2$.

Comment: you mean $f(5)= 265$?

Comment: No, $60\binom 44+25=60+25$...

Comment: oh, man, I'm sorry, now I got it, $f(5)=85$

Comment: $\binom{x-1}4={(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\over 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}$

Comment: And I made a calculation error, it should be $\binom 64=15$ leading to constant $a=24$...

Comment: So, $f(5)=24+25=49$?

Comment: @abiessu: You should remove the incorrect extra $x$ in your main formula.

Comment: @MårtenW: I'm pretty sure that $x^2=2\binom x2+x$...

Comment: @abiessu: Yes, you're right, too late for me to be reading formulas :) However, it would be clearer if you just wrote $x^2+a\binom{x-1}{4}$.

Comment: @mame: that is correct

Comment: @MårtenW: true, I'll update here soon

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a fourth-degree polynomial function, you have
$$
f(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e.
$$
if $f(7)=406$ then $a\cdot7^4 + b\cdot73 + c\cdot7^2 + d\cdot7 + e = 409$, or $2401a + 343b + 49c + 7d+e=406$.  That's an equation in five variables, $a,b,c,d,e$.  If you have five such equations, you can find $a,b,c,d,e$.

That's the brute-force way to do it.

Here's another way:

Consider $\displaystyle\vphantom{\frac\int\int}\frac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-7)}{(4-1)(4-2)(4-3)(4-7)}$. This is a fourth-degree polynomial equal to $1$ when $x=4$ and equal to $0$ when $x=\text{either 1, 2, 3, or 7}$.  Since you want $f(4)$ to be $16$, multiply this by $16$ and you have something equal to $16$ when $x=4$ and equal to $0$ when $x=1,2,3,\text{ or }7$.

In the same way, create a fourth-degree polynomial equal to $409$ when $x=7$ and equal to $0$ when $x=\text{either 1, 2, 3, or 4}$.

And one equal to $9$ when $x=3$ and equal to $0$ when $x = \text{1, 2, 4, or 7}$.

And so on.

Then add all five of them together.

Comment: sorry, $f(7)=409$